# How can I add a countdown on my website with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I wanted to add a countdown to my website. This is what I have so far. The problem is that is doesn't show the javascript coding to the html. Maybe there is a problem in the javascript coding because I dont think that it has sm to do with the html file.

```js
    const countdown = () => {
      const countDate = new Date("November 7, 2021 00:00:00").getTime();
      const now = new Date().getTime();
      const gap = countDate - now;
    
      const second = 1000;
      const minute = second * 60;
      const hour = minute * 60;
      const day = hour * 24;
    
      const textDay = Math.floor(gap / day);
      const textHour = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
      const textMinute = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
      const textSecond = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);
    
    
           document.querySelector('.day').innerText = textDay;
           document.querySelector('.hour').innerText = textHour;
           document.querySelector('.minute').innerText = textMinute;
           document.querySelector('.second').innerText = textSecond;
    };
    
    setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

```html
   <section class="coming-soon">
              <div>
                <h3>Bis zum EMS...</h3>
                <div class="countdown">
                  <div class="container-day">
                    <h4 class="day">Time</h4>
                    <h4>Day</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="container-hour">
                    <h4 class="hour">Time</h4>
                    <h4>Hour</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="container-minute">
                    <h4 class="minute">Time</h4>
                    <h4>Minute</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="container-second">
                    <h4 class="second">Time</h4>
                    <h4>Second</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
```

it doesnt work but I haven't figured out why. Can sm help?

Comment: Hi and welcome! What do you mean "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me, after I wrap the Javascript in `<script>`/`</script>` tags.  You did put the code in script tags, didn't you?  I have a very similar page I use to drive a digital clock here that you can look at:  http://timr.4roberts.us/clock.html

Comment: It just shows the html but not the js.
And yes I have put the <script>/<script> tags. :(

Comment: @pinar i put your code on snippet and it seems to work, doesn't it?

Comment: Haha thats true it works on snippet, i just realized. But why doesnt it work on my website? Is it because its just a "live server of the html file" and not like on a real server?

Comment: What is the error in the console? How do you include the script on the page. The code runs fine so you need to figure out what is different from here compared to what you have.

Comment: I figured out what the "error" was. In the <script>... tag I had written type=text/javascript and somehow this caused it not to work

Answer (score -1):

Here's a sample pulled from what I use on a site.
It uses jQuery, moment js, moment timezone, and moment timezone with data.
https://jsfiddle.net/mdzLhvqw/1/

```
<div class="timer"></div>
<script>
$(function(){
  let end=moment("2021-11-07T00:00:00").tz('America/New_York');
  let timer=setInterval(function(){
    let now=moment().tz('America/New_York');
    let diff=moment.duration(end.diff(now));
    let days=diff.get("days")<1?'':(diff.get("days")>1?diff.get("days")+'days ':diff.get("days")+"day ");
    let hr=diff.get("hours")<2?diff.get("hours")+'hr ':diff.get("hours")+'hrs ';
    let mn=diff.get("minutes")<2?diff.get("minutes")+"min ":diff.get("minutes")+"mins ";
    let sec=diff.get("seconds")<2?diff.get("seconds")+"sec":diff.get("seconds")+"secs";
    $(".timer").text(days+hr+mn+sec);
    if(now>=end){
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  },1000);
});
</script>
```